# Display a loading bar during the retrieve data time

Tags: reactjs, react-table

Goal:
Display a loading bar, in the table, during the time when you retrieve the data from backend.

Problem:
Is it possible to do it?

Codesandbox:
https://codesandbox.io/s/exciting-ganguly-7w2d84

Info:
*Tried find some information in documenation but nothing is written about it.
*New in react table.

Thank you!

---

App.js

```
import React from 'react'
import styled from 'styled-components'
import { useTable } from 'react-table'

import makeData from './makeData'

const Styles = styled.div`
  padding: 1rem;

  table {
    border-spacing: 0;
    border: 1px solid black;

    tr {
      :last-child {
        td {
          border-bottom: 0;
        }
      }
    }

    th,
    td {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0.5rem;
      border-bottom: 1px solid black;
      border-right: 1px solid black;

      :last-child {
        border-right: 0;
      }
    }
  }
`

function Table({ columns, data }) {
  // Use the state and functions returned from useTable to build your UI
  const {
    getTableProps,
    getTableBodyProps,
    headerGroups,
    rows,
    prepareRow,
  } = useTable({
    columns,
    data,
  })

  // Render the UI for your table
  return (
    <table {...getTableProps()}>
      <thead>
        {headerGroups.map(headerGroup => (
          <tr {...headerGroup.getHeaderGroupProps()}>
            {headerGroup.headers.map(column => (
              <th {...column.getHeaderProps()}>{column.render('Header')}</th>
            ))}
          </tr>
        ))}
      </thead>
      <tbody {...getTableBodyProps()}>
        {rows.map((row, i) => {
          prepareRow(row)
          return (
            <tr {...row.getRowProps()}>
              {row.cells.map(cell => {
                return <td {...cell.getCellProps()}>{cell.render('Cell')}</td>
              })}
            </tr>
          )
        })}
      </tbody>
    </table>
  )
}

function App() {
  const columns = React.useMemo(
    () => [
      {
        Header: 'Name',
        columns: [
          {
            Header: 'First Name',
            accessor: 'firstName',
          },
          {
            Header: 'Last Name',
            accessor: 'lastName',
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        Header: 'Info',
        columns: [
          {
            Header: 'Age',
            accessor: 'age',
          },
          {
            Header: 'Visits',
            accessor: 'visits',
          },
          {
            Header: 'Status',
            accessor: 'status',
          },
          {
            Header: 'Profile Progress',
            accessor: 'progress',
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
    []
  )

  const data = React.useMemo(() => makeData(20), [])

  return (
    <Styles>
      <Table columns={columns} data={data} />
    </Styles>
  )
}

export default App
```

---

makeData.js

```
import namor from 'namor'

const range = len => {
  const arr = []
  for (let i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    arr.push(i)
  }
  return arr
}

const newPerson = () => {
  const statusChance = Math.random()
  return {
    firstName: namor.generate({ words: 1, numbers: 0 }),
    lastName: namor.generate({ words: 1, numbers: 0 }),
    age: Math.floor(Math.random() * 30),
    visits: Math.floor(Math.random() * 100),
    progress: Math.floor(Math.random() * 100),
    status:
      statusChance > 0.66
        ? 'relationship'
        : statusChance > 0.33
        ? 'complicated'
        : 'single',
  }
}

export default function makeData(...lens) {
  const makeDataLevel = (depth = 0) => {
    const len = lens[depth]
    return range(len).map(d => {
      return {
        ...newPerson(),
        subRows: lens[depth + 1] ? makeDataLevel(depth + 1) : undefined,
      }
    })
  }

  return makeDataLevel()
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible, but your `makeData()` function is synchronous, if you get data from a web service, it will be `async` function, so I made some changes assuming `makeData` is async,

I made your `makeData()` function async (assume that you will get data from an endpoint).

```
export default async function makeData(...lens) {
  const makeDataLevel = (depth = 0) => {
    const len = lens[depth];
    return range(len).map((d) => {
      return {
        ...newPerson(),
        subRows: lens[depth + 1] ? makeDataLevel(depth + 1) : undefined
      };
    });
  };

  return Promise.resolve(makeDataLevel());
}
```

Keep the `data` in the state because `makeData` is async, data default value is an empty array. (setTimeout needs to be removed, added it to see `loading...` clearly)

```
const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  React.useMemo(
    () =>
      makeData(1000).then((res) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
          setData(res);
        }, 2000); //put 2sec to be able to see loading...
      }),
    []
  );
```

and I have added this line in the table
`{rows.length === 0 && <tr><td>loading...</td></tr>}`

```
  <tbody {...getTableBodyProps()}>
        {rows.map((row, i) => {
            prepareRow(row);
            return (
            <tr {...row.getRowProps()}>
                {row.cells.map((cell) => {
                return (
                    <td {...cell.getCellProps()}>{cell.render("Cell")}</td>
                );
                })}
            </tr>
            );
        })}
        {rows.length === 0 && <tr><td>loading...</td></tr>}
    </tbody>
```

See the full changes:
https://codesandbox.io/s/nifty-smoke-9m5jup?file=/src/App.js